# Proving length of chords in a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

$M$ is the midpoint of the chord $AB$ of circle $C(O,r)$. Show that if a different chord $ CD $ contains $M$, then $ AB < CD $ .(You may use Pythagoras's Theorem)

Let $ \Delta CBM\sim \Delta ADM  $, $ BM = x  $ and $MA =x$

I have that $\frac{CM}{MA} = \frac{BM}{DM} \rightarrow x^2 = (CM)(MD) $

by$ A.M. - G.M.$  i have  $  CM+MD \geq  2x $

if $ CM + MD = 2x $ then chord $CD $ is chord $AB$.

if 
$ CM+ MD > 2x $ then chord $CD$ is other chord that is not chord $AB$ .

so I can conclude that  $ AB< CD $.

I want to know if there's a way to prove this using Pythagoras's theorem or other way, and, is my solution correct ?

Comment: The implication of "if CM+MD=2x then chord CD is chord AB." is incorrect. Think of the case that AB and CD are diameters, they are intersecting at M (the center in this particular case) and they are equal in length but AB is NOT CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, here's another possible way.

$OM$ is perpendicular to $AB$ and is not perpendicular to $CD$. Hence the midpoint $N$ of $CD$ is different from $M$ and $ON<OM$ (because in right triangle $ONM$ side $OM$ is the hypothenuse). It follows then from Pythagoras's theorem:
$$
CN=\sqrt{r^2-ON^2}>\sqrt{r^2-OM^2}=AM.
$$